# boost::asio set_option error

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

I have a simple `boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor` which does almost nothing - it accepts connections in an infinite loop. I then have a number of connectors running at the same time trying to connect...

```
pSocket->async_connect(endpoint, 
        [=](boost::system::error_code error)
        {
            if(!error)
            {
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay noDelay(true);
                pSocket->set_option(noDelay, error);
                assert(!error);
                std::cout << error.message() << '\n'; // "An invalid argument was supplied"
            }
        });
```

Everything is running in infinite loops and I'm running 2 clients and 1 server, all loopback connections. After a while (hundreds of successful connects and disconnects) when setting the `no_delay` option on the connected socket I get the error `An invalid argument was supplied`.

Under what conditions can setting an option on a socket cause this error?
Has anyone seen this before, and know why it's happening and/or a way to fix it?

**Update:**
If I change the set `set_option` to something like...

```
do
{
    pSocket->set_option(noDelay, error);
} while(error);
```

...it will succeed - usually on the second try after it fails.

Comment: @SamMiller Visual Studio 2010

Comment: It sounds like race condition. Ensure that you never try to access your socket simultaneously from multiple threads.

Answer (score 3):

Yesterday i debug set_option step by step, problem that set_option uses io_service_impl object but it contains bad socket pointer, that's why it crushes. But on socket creation nothing is set this socket, so i think you cant set option on socket in this way.

You must open socket before set_option, try this before `async_connect` and `set_option`:

```
sock->open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());
```

Error is called `Bad file descriptor` which direct on non-initialized socket on set_option call.

Comment: The error isn't even in the application with an `acceptor`. It's in the client, which calls `async_connect`

Comment: I'm not setting options on the accept side... Like I said - all this is on the connect side.

Comment: If I do it before the connect I get "The file handle supplied is not valid" - lol... worthless error.

Comment: The way I'm doing it works 99 times out of a hundred before it ever fails. Interestingly on the fail case if I detect it and simply call the same thing again, it succeeds.