# Setting ASIO no_delay option

Tags: tcp, boost-asio

I'm having troubles setting the no_delay option on an asio socket.  The following code runs well, except for the delay.  My server receives the messages only after the 5000 ms expire.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
using namespace boost::asio;
struct Client
{
   io_service svc;
   ip::tcp::socket sock;

   Client() : svc(), sock(svc)
   {
       ip::tcp::resolver resolver(svc);
       ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint = resolver.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query("127.0.0.1", "32323"));
       connect(sock, endpoint);
   }

   void send(std::string const& message) {
       sock.send(buffer(message));
   }
};

int main()
{
   Client client;

   client.send("hello world\n");
   client.send("bye world\n");

   boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
}
```

When trying to add a delay I have a few options:
1) Add the option before connection:

```
Client() : svc(), sock(svc)
{
   ip::tcp::resolver resolver(svc);
   ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint = resolver.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query("127.0.0.1", "32323"));

   sock.set_option(ip::tcp::no_delay(true));
   connect(sock, endpoint);
}
```

However this throws `set_option: Bad file descriptor`

2) Add the option after the connection:

```
Client() : svc(), sock(svc)
{
   ip::tcp::resolver resolver(svc);
   ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint = resolver.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query("127.0.0.1", "32323"));

   connect(sock, endpoint);
   sock.set_option(ip::tcp::no_delay(true));
}
```

However in this case, the option has no effect and I still see the delay.  According to [boost::asio with no_delay not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090155/boostasio-with-no-delay-not-possible) , I need to set the option after I've opened the socket but before I've connected the socket.  So I've tried this:

```
Client() : svc(), sock(svc)
{
     ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint( ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 32323);
     sock.open(ip::tcp::v4());
     sock.set_option(ip::tcp::no_delay(true));
     sock.connect(endpoint);
}
```

However, I still see no effect.  How can I set this option?

**Edit:**  It's possible that I am not setting the option correctly on the server-side.  This is the complete server code:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service        io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 32323));
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket   socket(io_service);

    acceptor.accept(socket);
    socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true));

    boost::asio::streambuf sb;
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    while (boost::asio::read(socket, sb, ec)) {
        std::cout << "received:\n" << &sb;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the server also have `no_delay` option set ?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I wasn't setting it on the server side.  I think I am setting it now, but still don't see the effects.  I've edited the original post to include the server code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client is properly setting the [`ip::tcp::no_delay`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/no_delay.html) option.  However, the delay being observed is not the result of this  option.  Instead, it is the result of the server attempting to read more data than the client has sent, and when the client exits after sleeping 5000ms, the server's read operation completes with an error.

The [`read()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload6.html) operation initiated by the server will complete when either it has read [`streambuf.max_size()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/max_size.html) bytes or an error occurs.  The streambuf's max size defaults to `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()` and can be configured in its  [constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/basic_streambuf.html).  In this case, the server attempts to read  `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()` bytes, but the client only sends 22 bytes, sleeps 5000ms, then closes the socket.  When the server observes that connection has closed, the `read()` operation completes with 22 bytes read and an error code of `boost::asio::error::eof`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  I was just reading through [Boost's chat client example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/chat/chat_client.cpp) and was trying to figure out why they sent the buffer size in the first byte of data.  This explains it.  Thanks for the info.