# How to call boost async_connect as member function using lamba as connect handler

Tags: c++, boost, asio

I implemented `async_connect` successfully using it as a free function and a lambda as connect_handler as follows:

```
auto self(shared_from_this());
boost::asio::async_connect(m_socket, endpoint_iter, [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::iterator){...}
```

However, now I'm forced to use the `no_delay` flag. Regarding this entry [boost::asio with no_delay not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090155/boostasio-with-no-delay-not-possible) I have to call async_connect as member function of the socket. Trying as following

```
m_socket.async_connect(endpoint_iter->endpoint(), [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::iterator){...}
```

my compiler (VS2013) gives me an error `Error 1 error C2338: ConnectHandler type requirements not met`

Does someone has as idea, how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The handler signature of the free function [`async_connect`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_connect/overload1.html) should be:

```
void handler(const boost::system::error_code& error, Iterator iterator);
```

The handler signature of the member function [`basic_stream_socket::async_connect`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_connect.html) should be:

```
void handler(const boost::system::error_code& error);
```

The reasoning is that you give multiple endpoints to the free function which then gives you back an iterator to tell you which one was connected while you only give one endpoint to the member function which doesn't have to tell you which one was connected since you only provided one.

So in order for you code to work you most likely just have to remove the iterator from the parameters of your lambda callback:

```
m_socket.async_connect(endpoint_iter->endpoint(), [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec){...}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just verified it and it's working!